# Import .sql data file in Advanced Installer

Tags: mysql, advanced-installer

I would make a setup. I use advanced installer. I would install mysql server and import .sql data file during the setup. I choose mysql server in requirements > prerequisites. But I see a folder "mysql server" in the output folder. I don't would a folder. Because in the another computer how can I install mysql? And I can't open the mysql command line client.

Comment: Is the folder created under your application's folder?  Is that where it's installing the server or is it just creating an empty folder?

Comment: The folder is created in the setup folder. This name is : "MySQL Server 5.7". İndoor the folder there is mysql server 5.7.exe

Comment: Is that the setup .exe?  If so, you could add a cleanup action to that folder within Advanced Installer's Files section.  Any log lines related to that folder and/or .exe could be added to the question to help the diagnostic process.